# After iOS update video playback in my app is distorted (OpenGL-ES-2). Anyone knows this effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, opengl-es-2.0

I have an app which is a couple of years old (not made by me, and I just started to get into iOS dev) - using OpenGL-ES-2 for displaying local videos.

The texture gets displayed correctly in DEBUG mode. This error only occurs in RELEASE mode (XCode 8.3.3 + XCode 9 beta).

I think the video gets displayed within two vertices, hence resulting in this graphic error within 2 triangles.

Did anyone experience this before and could lead me in the right direction? Any hints are very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The "Optimization level" was set to "fastest, smallest". I had to change it to "none". After the change, everything worked as expected.

[Adjust optimization level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbNl1.png)